# How to modify and recompile android SDK?

Tags: android

For research purposes i need to modify an Android SDK class source.

Can i just modify the class, recompile and generate android.jar to use it in my Eclipse project with the emulator? If so, how can i do that?

As stated [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.5/development/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt) i tried with:

```
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch sdk-eng
make sdk
```

but i think these instructions are obsolete, i don't find the `build` folder nor the `envsetup.sh`

I'm on ubuntu linux 14.04 32bit, android 4.2.2

Comment: "For research purposes i need to modify an Android SDK class source" -- that probably won't do you much good, unless you are also going to create a custom emulator image or custom firmware that also contains your changes.

Comment: Also for Android beyond Gingerbread (2.3.x) you need a 64-bit system: http://source.android.com/source/building.html

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, a custom emulator image is what i need